# Physics inconsistent even when using FixedUpdate() or Time.DeltaTime()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want to move a rigidBody2D for a fixed amount of time with a fixed amount of velocity, when the player presses a button. I am calling the method in FixedUpdate() and the results are not consistent. Sometimes the rigidBody will travel more and sometimes less (Here is a relevant part of my code how i went about do this)

```
 void Update()
 {
     GetPlayerInput();
 }
 private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     GroundCheck();
     ApplayNormalPlayerMovement();
     ApplyMove(); // This is the method of interest - I tried calling this in Update() with Time.DeltaTime - still inconsistent results.
     MoveCooldownCounter(); // I tried calling this in Update() - inconsistent results also
 }
 IEnumerator MoveRB()
 {
     savedVelocityX = rb.velocity.x;
     rb.gravityScale = 0;
     savedXinput = xInput;
     while (moveTimer >= 0)
     {
         if (xInput != 0)
             xInput = 0;
         cc.sharedMaterial = noFriction;
         if (facingRight)
         {
             rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, .0f); // I tried multiplying the moveSpeed by Time.DeltaTime and FixedDeltaTime - still inconsistent results.
         } else
         {
             rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, .0f);
         }
         moveTimer -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
         yield return null;
     }
     moveTimer= moveDuration;
     rb.gravityScale = gravity;
     rb.velocity = new Vector2 (savedVelocityX, .0f);
     xInput = savedXinput;
     moveCooldownInternal -= Time.deltaTime; // I tried changing this to a specific float - still inconsistent results in physics..
 }
 private void MoveCooldownCounter()
 {
     if (moveCooldownInternal != moveCooldown)
     {
         moveCooldownInternal -= Time.deltaTime;
         if (moveCooldownInternal <= 0)
         {
             moveCooldownInternal = moveCooldown;
         }
         if (moveCooldownInternal == moveCooldown && isGrounded)
             canMove = true;
     }
 }
 private void ApplyMove()
 {
     if (b_Fire3 && canMove)
     {
         StartCoroutine("MoveRB");
         canMove= false;
     }
 }
```

Side note: right now i experience player input loss on occasions because i call this ApplyMove() in FixedUpdate() (will have to find a workaround for that as well - naturally if I can call the ApplyMove in Update() and get consistent results than this issue would be fixed).

Pleas excise my newbiness, i am trying to learn :)

Thank you in advance!

Add comment

Comment: Try using Time.fixedDeltaTime instead.

Comment: I did try that, forgot to mention it (maybe i am missing something - exactly where should i use the Time.fixedDeltaTime)?

Comment: Everywhere where you currently use deltaTime. Delta time is a time which has passed since last update, it always variable and depends on a frame rate.  This is why rigid body travels different distance. Fixed Delta time is used in physics simulation which is performed multiple times per frame and is always the same. It should give you consistency.

Comment: Also  you didn't post move duration calculation. It seems that it should stop the body. Make sure that you calculate it with fixed Delta time as well, insides fixed update

Answer (score 0):

Unity is a game engine. All game engines are based on the [game loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_programming#Game_structure) - however Unity somewhat hides if from you, behind the 3 Update functions.

Not all parts are equally important. Drawing is generally skipped when the GPU is not ready or the FPS are capped. And Drawing and physics are generally calculated independantly of one another (unless you really messed up the development).

With Physics and Animations, you generally want to stuff to be consistent to the Game Tick Counter, **not** real time. All movement of game pieces and all animation should count in game ticks. Real Time is a nice figure and all, but ticks can have wildly different processing times. Especially since the CPU side drawing work also has to run in the same thread.

Just figure out your maximum ticks/second. And if you want to run something to run for "roughly" 10 ingame seconds, you multiply that value. It does not mater if the game on this machine needs 2 seconds for 200 ticks or 2 minutes for 200 ticks - with the number of ticks, the results will be consistent (unless the math itself is inprecise, like floating point math).

Answer (score 0):

If it's **not** multiplayer game, it does not have to be hackproof and thus easiest fix is to capture the first frame of the button pressed and apply the force only on that frame, because of that we have to capture input on the Update function and also there immadietly apply the force even though it's suggested to do physics stuff in fixed update, but if you use delta time in update function for calculation it should be fine!

Now I think you know how to do that but I'll write it anyway we can either use apply force or set the velocity,

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y + 5f*Time.deltaTime);
}
```

**Note:** I didn't test it but it should be allright since GetKeyDown returns true only on the first frame when the button was pressed,

If it was just GetKey and in case of jump we would check the grounding of player, we could be during jump and still be grounded on the second frame even if we jumped because of not really precise ground checking.

PS. Use fixedDeltaTime in fixedUpdate method!